# Не срабатывает анимация перехода при старте фрагмента

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, android-animation

Есть `DrawerLayout`. Выбираю на нем пункт меню и открывается фрагмент. Мне нужен переход (анимация). Вот код фрагмента:

```
public class RulesFragment extends Fragment {
private View myView;
private static final String TAG = "myLogs";

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.trans_left_in, R.anim.trans_left_out);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rules, container, false);
    Log.d(TAG, "RulesFragment");
    getActivity().setTitle(R.string.nav_rules);
    return myView;
}
```

}

Вот разметка фрагмента:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/rules_title_text"
            android:textColor="?attr/editTextColor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/size_textview_phrase"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/rules_text"
            android:textColor="?attr/editTextColor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/size_textview_phrase"
            android:textStyle="normal" />
    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Просьба подсказать, в чем проблема. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Вы хотите анимировать фрагмент при клике в боковом меню?

Comment: Да, когда боковое меню открываю и выбираю фрагмент, хочу чтобы он "выплывал".

Comment: http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/animation/fragmentsanimation.php

Comment: спасибо, первый вариант `fTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);` вроде работает (хотя и не сильно заметно), а вот второй вариант не проходит `fTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.slide_in_left, R.animator.slide_in_right);` подчеркивает красным. Хотя в любом случае ві натолкнули меня на поиск, по другим критериям. Так что ваш ответ нужно сделать "ответом")

Comment: Тема эта многими протоптана, информации много, удачи! Ответ дан

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть замечательная статья - анимация фрагментов - http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/animation/fragmentsanimation.php.

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment, "fragment");
ft.commit();
```

Если вы используете `Fragment` из библиотеки поддержки, то вы должны использовать такого рода xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set>
<objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:propertyName="x" 
android:valueType="floatType"
android:valueFrom="-1280"
android:valueTo="0" 
android:duration="500"/>
</set>
```

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/140596)

Comment: Да, я просто отложил добавление кода. Все, исправил

Comment: а кто такая Самвра? У Вас в профиле

Comment: @alexolut, это опечатка. Город Самара. Просто я не могу поменять, не знаю как, через телефон сижу всегда. Да и забываю )